# Error: node not deployed. marantz avr in node-red

Tags: api, integration, node-red

have configured a flow for marantz. But, whenever I inject the node, it shows the

> Error: node not deployed.

[image]

I installed marantz node from node palette, hoping that I can control my marantz avr with that node using http. but, even though i have confirmed that i am getting ping for my device, the node inside node-red still shows inactive, as in the picture above.

Comment: Is there anything shown in the Node-RED logs (not the debug sidebar, the actual console output of the node-red process). If so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76170320/edit) the question to show it.

Comment: The debug sidebar doesn't show anything. As for the console output, please point me as to how do i access it? I will attach the screenshot of all I have done in just a bit.

Comment: Do not attach screen shots of text, post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it. I don't know how you are running Node-RED so I can't comment on where the logs would be.

Comment: I am using node-red in the Browser actually. Would it be alright if I contact you on Skype. I can phrase my questions and share my PC screen to show you everything clearly.

Comment: No, Node-RED doesn't run in the browser, the editor is accessed from the browser but it runs on elsewhere. You need to find where the output from the backend runs

Comment: Yes, it is running on my home automation server. I only know how to work in the editor, and program things. Can you help me a bit? If it's alright we can connect somewhere I can show you, what issue I am facing, be it via Zoom or Skype or whatever. Won't take more than 15 minutes of your time. Is it possible?